# Using a target size (torch.Size([400])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([400, 1]))

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I'm currently switching from tensorflow to pytorch and facing the warning `UserWarning: Using a target size (torch.Size([400])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([400, 1])). This will likely lead to incorrect results due to broadcasting. Please ensure they have the same size`
I came across that `unsqueeze(1)` on my target could help to resolve my problem, however, I do so obtain problems in regard of the multitarget which results from the shape my loss function (crossentropy) expects.

Here is a minimal example to my code:

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim 
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torch.nn.functional as F


X1 = torch.randn(400, 1, 9999)
X2 = torch.randn((400,1, 9999))
aux1 = torch.randn(400,1)
aux2 = torch.randn(400,1)
aux3 = torch.randn(400,1)
y1 = torch.rand(400,)
y2 = torch.rand(400,)
y3 = torch.rand(400,)

import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.optim as optim 
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader, TensorDataset
import torch.nn.functional as F



# In[18]:


class MultiTaskDataset:
    def __init__(self, 
                 amplitude, 
                 phase, 
                 weight,
                 temperature,
                 humidity,
                 shelf_life_clf,
                 shelf_life_pred,
                 thickness_pred
                 ):
        self.amplitude = amplitude
        self.phase = phase
        self.weight = weight
        self.temperature = temperature
        self.humidity = humidity
        self.shelf_life_clf = shelf_life_clf
        self.shelf_life_pred = shelf_life_pred
        self.thickness_pred = thickness_pred
        

    def __len__(self):
        return self.amplitude.shape[0]

    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        #inputs
        amplitude = self.amplitude[idx]
        phase = self.phase[idx]
        weight = self.weight[idx]
        temperature = self.temperature[idx]
        humidity = self.humidity[idx]
        
        #outputs
        shelf_life_clf = self.shelf_life_clf[idx]
        shelf_life_reg = self.shelf_life_pred[idx]
        thickness_pred = self.thickness_pred[idx]
        
        return ([torch.tensor(amplitude, dtype=torch.float32),
                torch.tensor(phase, dtype=torch.float32),
                torch.tensor(weight, dtype=torch.float32),
                torch.tensor(temperature, dtype=torch.float32),
                torch.tensor(humidity, dtype=torch.float32)],
                [torch.tensor(shelf_life_clf, dtype=torch.long),
                torch.tensor(shelf_life_reg, dtype=torch.float32),
                torch.tensor(thickness_pred, dtype=torch.float32)])


# In[19]:


# train loader
dataset = MultiTaskDataset(X1, X2, aux1, aux2, aux3, 
                           y1,y2,y3)
train_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=512, shuffle=True, num_workers=0)

# test loader



# In[20]:


class MyModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyModel, self).__init__()
        self.features_amp = nn.Sequential(
            nn.LazyConv1d(1, 3, 1),
        )
        self.features_phase = nn.Sequential(
            nn.LazyConv1d(1, 3, 1),
        )
        
        
        self.backbone1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.LazyConv1d(64,3,1),
            nn.LazyConv1d(64,3,1),
            nn.AvgPool1d(3),
            nn.Dropout(0.25),
        )
        
        self.backbone2 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(64, 32,3,1),
            nn.Conv1d(32, 32,3,1),
            nn.AvgPool1d(3),
            nn.Dropout(0.25),
        )
        
        self.backbone3 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv1d(32, 16,3,1),
            nn.Conv1d(16, 16,3,1),
            nn.AvgPool1d(3),
            nn.Dropout(0.25),
        )
        
        
        self.classifier = nn.LazyLinear(2)
        self.shelf_life_reg = nn.LazyLinear(1)
        self.thickness_reg = nn.LazyLinear(1)

    def forward(self, x1, x2, aux1, aux2, aux3):
        x1 = self.features_amp(x1)
        x2 = self.features_phase(x2)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
        x1 = x1.view(x1.size(0),-1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
        x2 = x2.view(x2.size(0),-1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
        x = torch.cat((x1, x2), dim=-1)
        print(x.size())

        x = x.unsqueeze(1)
        print(x.size())
        x = self.backbone1(x)
        print(x.size())

        x = torch.flatten(x, start_dim=1, end_dim=-1)

 
        x = torch.cat([x, aux1, aux2, aux3], dim=-1)
        
        
        shelf_life_clf = self.classifier(x)     
        shelf_life_reg = self.shelf_life_reg(x)
        thickness_reg = self.thickness_reg(x)
        return (shelf_life_clf,
                shelf_life_reg,
                thickness_reg)


model = MyModel()

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.003)

criterion1 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
criterion2 = nn.MSELoss()
criterion3 = nn.MSELoss()







# In[21]:


def train(epoch):
    model.train()
    #exp_lr_scheduler.step()
    arr_loss = []
    #first_batch = next(iter(train_loader))
    for batch_idx, (data, target) in enumerate(train_loader):
        #amp, phase = data
        clf, reg1, reg2 = target
        
        #print(amp.shape, phase.shape)
        #print(target[2].shape)

        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            device = torch.device("cuda:0" if torch.cuda.is_available() else "cpu")
            data = [data[i].cuda() for i in range(len(data))]
            target = [target[i].cuda() for i in range(len(target))]
            model.to(device)
  
            


        optimizer.zero_grad()
        output1, output2, output3 = model(*data)
        
        #losses
        loss = criterion1(output1, target[0].long())
        loss1 = criterion2(output2, target[1].float())
        loss2 = criterion3(output3, target[2].float())
        loss = loss + loss1 + loss2
        
        #metrices
        
        
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        print('Train Epoch: {} [{}/{} ({:.0f}%)]\tLoss: {:.6f}'.format(
                epoch, (batch_idx + 1) * len(data), len(train_loader.dataset),
                100. * (batch_idx + 1) / len(train_loader), loss.data))
        arr_loss.append(loss.data)
    return arr_loss

def averaged_accuracy(outputs, targets):
    assert len(outputs) != len(targets), "number of outputs should equal the number of targets"
    accuracy = []
    for i in range(len(outputs)):
        _, predicted = torch.max(output1.data, 1)
        total += target[0].size(0)
        correct += (predicted == target[0]).sum()
        acc = correct / total *100
        accuracy.append(acc)
    return torch.mean(accuracy)


# In[22]:

optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.00003)

criterion1 = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
criterion2 = nn.MSELoss()
criterion3 = nn.MSELoss()


n_epochs = 10

for epoch in range(n_epochs):
    train(epoch)
```

Can anybody provide guidance to resolve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide the error backtrace when applying the unsqueeze operation?

Comment: of course. no problem. you can find it above.

Comment: Thank you. What is your target shape for the cross entropy loss? And the shape of `output1` as well.

Comment: Yes I checked that and now both my ```target``` and ```output1``` are of shape torch.Size([400, 2]. However the problems that remains is that my loss is is not converging. For my data it remains nan. I didnt have that problem with tensorflow. I updated the code accordingly.

Comment: Which term of your loss is diverging to NaN values?

Comment: ```Loss``` is turning to NaN however this doesnt make the difference I think. I also know why this is the case since I had similar issue at the beginning with tensorflow. When you use hot encoding it leads to exploding gradients. What I'm trying to do is get my dimension to [400,1] without doing any hot encoding (since this leads to the issue).

Comment: I think it has to do with the concatenation ```torch.cat``` and my auxilary variables having the dimension [400,1] instead of [400,] however I'm still trying to work this out.

Comment: If you keep changing around, it is hard for me to keep track. If you want help, please provide a fixed state of your code along with its associated error backtrace.

Comment: The code provided above is the current state. Thank you for your help and guidance.

Comment: Please provide the error backtrace. Ideally you could create a mock of you dataset to reproduce your error in a minimal example.